# Django how to annotate manytomany field with count

Tags: django, annotations

Considger the following:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    model_as = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, db_index=True, related_name="model_bs", blank=True)


model_bs = model_a_object.model_bs.all()
for model_b in model_bs:
    print(model_b.model_as.count())
3
2
```

So far so good. But I want to create an ordered list of `model_bs` depending on the count of `model_as`. My understanding is that simply this should do the trick:

```
model_bs = model_a_object.model_bs.all().annotate(count=Count("model_as")).order_by('count')
```

For some reason that doesn't work. When I print to check, the annotated `count` is wrong!!

```
for model_b in model_bs:
    print(model_b.model_as.count(), model_b.count)
3 1
2 1
```

What did I do wrong? Here is the sql output for `print(model_bs.query)`:

```
SELECT "mobile_modelb"."id",
       "mobile_modelb"."modelb",
       COUNT(DISTINCT "mobile_modelb_model_as"."modela_id") AS "count"
FROM "mobile_modelb"
INNER JOIN "mobile_modelb_model_as" ON ("mobile_modelb"."id" = "mobile_modelb_model_as"."modelb_id")
WHERE "mobile_modelb_model_as"."modela_id" = 7
GROUP BY "mobile_modelb"."id"
ORDER BY "count" ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `distinct=True` to the Count.

```
model_bs = model_a_object.model_bs.all().annotate(
    count=Count("model_as", distinct=True)
).order_by('count')
```

EDIT:

The problem is because you're using `model_a_object.model_bs.all()`, you generate this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE "mobile_modelb_model_as"."modela_id" = 7
```

The solution may be to do:

```
ModelB.objects.annotate(
    count=Count("model_as")
).filter(model_as=model_object_a)
```

If that doesn't work, try using `values()` before `filter()` to define the GROUP BY correctly.

```
ModelB.objects.annotate(
    count=Count("model_as")
).values('id', 'count').filter(model_as=model_object_a)
```

Comment: Tried, no change sadly :(

Comment: Print out the query via `print(model_bs.query)`, format it via sqlformat.org and add it to your question.

Comment: I added the sql print as you recommended

Comment: @mrj I've updated the answer with a few other things to try.

Comment: Your first suggestion was already the correct answer. `ModelB.objects.annotate(
    count=Count("model_as")
).filter(model_as=model_object_a)` Thanks, that's one I wouldn't have found on my own. How did you know the `.all()` generated the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Because `model_a_object.model_bs.all()` will fetch all ModelB instances that are related to `model_a_object`. Plus I've been working with Django for a while so it's a bit easier to reason out why the ORM does certain things.